# Creating a shell-script with actions which demand user interaction

Tags: shell-script

How can I create a shell script containing some commands which need user input, for example

```
#!/bin/sh
useradd test
passwd test
```

The passwd command needs some input (the password). Can I serve this input via the shell script? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `passwd` command is specifically protected against this (I believe in order to reduce it's utility in brute-force password guessing attacks). It reads it's input only from a connected terminal and not from the usual STDIN - this makes it difficult to use it to script password changes.

But see the man page for `usermod`

Comment: So this is theoretically possible but especially not for setting passwords?

Comment: Yes, you can write a script that prompts for user input and which reads that user input into a variable. You can also write an interactive script that invokes `passwd` but, in that case, your script doesn't get to see any part of `passwd`'s user interaction and can't feed password values into `passwd`.

Comment: @strauberry: Answer updated

Answer (score 2):

Normally not since most programs which require a password will not read from *stdin* as regular UNIX processes do. Instead they will try to read in the password from the controlling tty.

If you want to script such applications you will have to use tools like *expect*.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

`$ ./input.sh foo bar baz`

**Source:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# input.sh

echo $0       # input.sh
echo $1       # foo
echo $3       # baz
```

Comment: So I could do something like this: passwd test echo $2 ?

Comment: As answered by the others, no, this script is just to show how you can pass arguments into the script.

Comment: `$argv[1]` is not valid syntax in bash. `$1` is the only proper way.

Comment: @grawity Thanks, fixed. Silly me, I've been using zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Use expect. An example [here](http://www.seanodonnell.com/code/?id=21)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set newpass [lindex $argv 1]
spawn passwd $username
expect {*password:}
send "$newpass\r"
expect {*password:}
send "$newpass\r"
```